# beam search to find best sequence in nlp

Tags: html

which nlp library tool is best for the implementation of beam search algorithm? i prefer java. Stanford and open nlp are providing their implementation code in github.

Answer (score 0):

PYNLPL has a beam search implementation. You could see if it is suitable for your task.

https://github.com/proycon/pynlpl